# Symfony request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Failed to load private key "/var/www/symfony/app/../var/jwt/private.pem"

Tags: symfony, ubuntu-16.04, symfony-3.3

I have Symfony 3.3 project with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle implemented on ubuntu.
I am getting this error on production:
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Failed to load private key "/var/www/symfony/app/../var/jwt/private.pem".
File "private.pem" exist. jwt_key_pass_phrase is set.
I tried to change ownership of private.pem to root and to www-data. It doesn't help.

If I use dev environnment ( adding to link app_dev.php), everything is working fine, I am getting token.

Why I am getting this error on production?

Comment: clear your prod cache or try to regenerate key

Comment: same issue here https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/366

Comment: Clear cache helped. Thanks habibun! After 2 hours debugging forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

clear your prod cache or try to regenerate the key again.

same issue here [github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/366](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/issues/366)